# sqlmx equivalent for oracle "with" clause

Tags: sqlmx

Is there an equivalent in sql/mx for Oracle's "with" clause?

I would like to run a query like this:

```
with x as (select ... from ...) select * from x;
```

It doesn't work in sql/mx, nor does

```
select * from (select ... from ...);
```

The only solution I can think of is to create a temporary table that has the data that would normally be in the "with" clause: has anyone else come across this problem?